# Updating Data in MongoDB from Apache Spark Streaming

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using the scala Api of Apache Spark Streaming to read from Kafka Server in a window with the size of a minute and a slide intervall of a minute.
The message from Kafka contain a timestamp from the moment they were sent and an arbitrary value. Each of the values is supposed to be reducedByKeyAndWindow and saved to the Mongo.

```
val messages = stream.map(record => (record.key, record.value.toDouble))

val reduced = messages.reduceByKeyAndWindow((x: Double , y: Double) => (x + y),
  Seconds(60), Seconds(60))


reduced.foreachRDD({ rdd =>
  import spark.implicits._
  val aggregatedPower = rdd.map({x => MyJsonObj(x._2, x._1)}).toDF()
  aggregatedPower.write.mode("append").mongo()
})
```

This works so far, however it is possible, that some message come with a delay, of a minute, which results leads to having two json objects with the same timestamp in the dataBase.

```
{"_id":"5aa93a7e9c6e8d1b5c486fef","power":6.146849997,"timestamp":"2018-03-14 15:00"}
{"_id":"5aa941df9c6e8d11845844ae","power":5.0,"timestamp":"2018-03-14 15:00"}
```

The Documentation of the mongo-spark-connector didn't help me with finding a solution.
Is there a smart way to query whether the timestamp in the current window is already in the database and if so update this value?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a smart way to query whether the timestamp in the current window is already in the database and if so update this value?

It seems that what you're looking for is a MongoDB operation called [upsert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option). Where an update operation will insert a new document if the criteria has no match, and update the fields if there is a match.

If you are using [MongoDB Connector for Spark](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/) v2.2+, whenever a Spark dataframe contains an `_id` field, the data will be `upserted`. Which means any existing documents with the same `_id` value will be updated and new documents without existing `_id` value in the collection will be inserted.

Now you could try to create an RDD using [MongoDB Spark Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/scala/aggregation/), specifying a [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) filter to query where `timestamp` matches the current window:

```
val aggregatedRdd = rdd.withPipeline(Seq(
                        Document.parse(
                                "{ $match: { timestamp : '2018-03-14 15:00' } }"
)))
```

Modify the value of `power` field, and then `write.mode('append')`.

You may also find [blog: Data Streaming MongoDB/Kafka](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-and-data-streaming-implementing-a-mongodb-kafka-consumer) useful as well. If you would like to write a Kafka consumer and directly insert into MongoDB applying your logics using [MongoDB Java Driver](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/)

Comment: I tried to add the pipeline to the foreachRDD Block, in various variatoins. I always get an Exception that "Unfortunately SparkContext in this MongoRDD is null.
This can happen after MongoRDD has been deserialized.
SparkContext is not Serializable, therefore it deserializes to null.
RDD transformations are not allowed inside lambdas used in other RDD transformations."